# How to hide this part of uitableview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I designed a uitable view like in the image below , I want to hide the part under the second section , which I write on it (<- I want to remove this part ->)

[image]

any suggestion to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you coppied the code from someone, this element is the fotter view for the second section. Look for the method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
```

end erase it. It should be out.

Comment: first of all what do u mean by If you coppied the code from someone , secondly could u give me example of how to earse it , this be created automatic

Comment: This footer would be visible if you coppied the code from someone and the method viewForFooterInSection was implemented. If you didn't coppied the code and used the IB to create your table, I don't know how to help you. I don't use IB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating the table with specific height in the Interface Builder or:

```
UITableView* pTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)];
```

Maybe you can also specify that scrolling is forbidden in order to show the contents that you want:

```
pTable.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return heights for the footer of the current section and header of the next section to reduce the gap between the two sections. This of course, if there are sections are the current section. If there are no more sections, then you can just reduce the frame size.

Comment: I want to set it to the minimal value , do u know the default of the footer size

Comment: I am not entirely sure of the footer size. What confuses me are the stripes below the region you want to remove. Are they part of another table view?

Comment: yes they are , if u find any information about footer size tell me